# Configure Kendo UI ASP.NET MVC a razor view to display a checkbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-mvc

How can I configure a kendo ui grid with asp.net mvc to display a checkbox?

At the moment I just see true/false values...

Comment: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-inline | http://www.telerik.com/forums/display-boolean-field-as-checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Client template for that column. Somethigs like

```
columns.Bound(c => c.BooleanColumn).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' #= BooleanColumn ? checked='checked' : '' # disabled='disabled' ></input>");
```

Comment: I used this but no chance for a razor template?

Comment: Maybe you can try something like this                                 `columns.Bound(c => c.BooleanColumn).Format("<input type='checkbox' name='checkedRecords' disabled='disabled' value='{0}'  id ='{0}'/>").Encoded(false);`